# Reference of new object in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following method I'd like to test in combination with MOQ:

```
public Company CreateCompany(Company company)
{
    UnitOfWork.CompanyRepository.Insert(company);
    //Give the user who created a company all permissions
    UnitOfWork.CompanyPermissionRepository.Insert(new CompanyPermission
    {
        Useraccount = UnitOfWork.UseraccountRepository.GetByID(this.GetLoggedInUseraccount(this.Context.Session).Id),
        Company = company,
        AddUser = true,
        CreateProject = true,
        DeleteCompany = true,
        DeleteFile = true,
        DownloadFile = true,
        EditCompany = true,
        ManageProjectPermission = true,
        RemoveUser = true,
        UploadFile = true
   });
   UnitOfWork.Save();

   return company;
```

}

I basically want to check if the new `CompanyPermission` object was inserted to the repository:

```
companyPermissionRepository.Verify(r => r.Insert(companyPermissions.allCompanyPermissions));
```

This is my setup:

```
companyPermissionRepository = new Mock<IGenericRepository<CompanyPermission>>();
unitOfWork.Setup(r => r.CompanyPermissionRepository).Returns(companyPermissionRepository.Object);
```

My `allCompanyPermissions` object in unit-test is created with the same values like in the CreateCompany-method but the unit-test fails. I think this is because the two objects have the same values, but have different references- there are 2 objects in memory which are "different". Is this correct? How would I be able to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are inserting a new `CompanyPermission` object everytime, and it does not take any parameter from its dependency, there are two things that come to mind.

You could just test that `CompanyPermissionRepository.Insert` was called with a `CompanyPermission` object.

```
companyPermissionRepository.Verify(r => r.Insert(It.IsAny<CompanyPermission>());
```

Or, if you want to be thorough (recommended), use Moq's `It.Is`

```
companyPermissionRepository.Verify(r => r.Insert(It.Is<CompanyPermission>(cp => cp.AddUser=true && ....)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Will follow your recommendation. :)